# Switch with an aggregate function

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I have the below table, the Total Is derived from a count expression,

```
=count(fields!Total.value)


Department        Total
HR                 50
H&S                60
Data               90
```

I would like to add some background colour dependent on the values in the total column.  For example anything less than 49 would be red anything greater would be green.

I have tried the following (ABC - being the dataset)

```
=switch(count(fields!Total.value <= "49", "red"),"ABC")
```

I get the error the scope parameter is not valid for an aggregate function

Comment: Your dataset is not right - based on your expression, it is looking for dataset `red`. Flip red and ABC and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: Thank you, yes that's one issue sorted. However it still doesn't seem to be picking up the 'count total' in the conditional formatting. It just seems to be looking at the figure in the in the 'Total' field. Should have used a better field name as an example - the total field is more of an ID field hence the count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the syntax looks off.. should it not be

```
=switch(count(fields!Total.value) <= 49, "red", True, "green")
```

`IIF` would make more since if its just 2 options

```
=iif(count(fields!Total.value) <= 49, "red", "green")
```

Comment: this works thank you, but how would i go about if i require more than 2 options?